# How to reduce 10+ union select statements

Tags: sql-server, union

I need to extract a single column of data from 10+ columns of a single table. Instead of stacking up 10+ union select statements, is there another way of doing this without repeating the union select statements for each column?

I can get it by stacking up 10+ select statements like below:

```
select 'column_5' from table_a
union
select 'column_6' from table_a  
union 
select 'column_7' from table_a
union
.
.
.
union
select 'column_18' from table_a
```

Thanks for your time in advance :)

Comment: You should not have `column_6`, `column_7`... in the first place. If several columns are storing the same kind of information, it should be normalised and broken off into another table.

Comment: Our situation is a bit different, the columns are holding different types of services and some of the values among the services are the same, my colleague wanted to create a pool holding distinct values of all the services to support another function. However you are correct in general situation that a table should not have multiple columns storing the same kind of information. Thanks for the reply :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `Cross Apply` or `UnPivot` you can avoid multiple `UNION` statements

```
select Distinct COL
from table 
Cross apply
(
values 
(column_1),
(column_2),
..
..
(column_18)
) 
CS (COL)
```

**Note :** Since you have used `UNION` i have kept `Distinct` in `select`. If you don't want to remove duplicates then remove Distinct from `select`

Comment: `cross apply` should also be more efficient than `union all`.  If the OP really wants `union`, then the query should be `select distinct col`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - Yep added. :)

Comment: Thank you so much Indian and Gordon! I am a newbie to sql and was stuck with this for the whole morning. You saved my day.

Answer (score 1):

A query with UNPIVOT would look something like this....

```
SELECT *
FROM TableName t 
  UNPIVOT (Vals FOR N IN (Column1, Column2, Column3,....,Column10))up
```

Important note all the columns in `IN` clause must be of the same data type, if they are not use a sub-query to convert them to a uniform data type and then unpivot them something like...

```
SELECT *
FROM (
 SELECT  CAST(Column1 AS VARCHAR(200)) AS Column1
        ,CAST(Column2 AS VARCHAR(200)) AS Column2
        ,CAST(Column3 AS VARCHAR(200)) AS Column3
        ,.....
        ,CAST(Column10 AS VARCHAR(200)) AS Column10
FROM TableName) t 
  UNPIVOT (Vals FOR N IN (Column1, Column2, Column3,....,Column10))up
```

Comment: Thanks Ali for the reply. It did not get what I was after, but UNPIVOT is something I want to learn, I will note down your tips and play with it.